# My python code s running properly on solo learning app but not on pc

Tags: python

I wrote a code on solo learning app and it worked properly but when I typed it on my computer it didn't work properly and it gave me other results.

The code is supposed to return only the unique numbers in that list and remove duplications.

```
no_list = [22,22,2,1,11,11,2,2,3,3,3,4,5,5,5,55,55,66]

def unique_list(l):
    l.sort()
    answer = []
    for i in range(len(l)):
        if i > 0:
            if l[i] != l[i-1]:
                answer.append(l[i])
            else:
                answer.append(l[0])
    return answer


print(unique_list(no_list))
```

The code returned the right answer on solo learning app which is:

> `[1,2,3,4,5,11,22,55,66]`

But on PC it returned:

> `[2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 4, 5, 1, 1, 11, 1, 22, 1, 55, 1, 66]`.

Comment: That's exactly what this code will output. Remove the `else` clause and it should work fine. (You'll also have to manually add `l[0]` at the start of `answer`)

Comment: I don't know what solo learning is, but if it gave the first output for this code, it has a bug in how it runs Python code. I can't imagine how a bug would even produce that output for this exact code, so my guess is that you are not actually running that code on solo learning and are misinterpreting what is occurring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your 'else' condition is not indented correctly:

Check this:

```
no_list = [22,22,2,1,11,11,2,2,3,3,3,4,5,5,5,55,55,66]

def unique_list(l):
    l.sort()
    answer = []
    for i in range(len(l)):
        if i > 0:
            if l[i] != l[i-1]:
                answer.append(l[i])
        else:
            answer.append(l[0])
    return answer


print(unique_list(no_list))
```

Although, here's another approach:

```
no_list = [22,22,2,1,11,11,2,2,3,3,3,4,5,5,5,55,55,66]
print(list(set(no_list)))
```